# Getting error in downloading vedio throughout the code

Tags: python, solution

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import instaloader
from .. import bot 




# Create an Instaloader instance
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True ,pattern='/download'))
async def download_instagram_video(event):
    if event.reply_to_msg_id is None:
        await event.reply('Please reply to an Instagram video message with /download.')
        return

    reply_msg = await event.get_reply_message()
    if reply_msg.media is None:
        await event.reply('The replied message is not a video.')
        return

    try:
        video = await bot.download_media(reply_msg.media, file='video.mp4')
        await event.reply('Video downloaded successfully!')
    except Exception as e:
        await event.reply(f'Error occurred while downloading the video: {str(e)}')
```

[WARNING/2023-06-11 12:39:01,029] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 1 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

[WARNING/2023-06-11 12:39:02,032] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 2 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable